# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_favorite'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to automated twitter a bit, but I get a following error on auto like feature on Tweepy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dusandev/Desktop/TwitterBot/bot.py", line 15, in <module>
tweet.favorite()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/tweepy/models.py", line 375, in favorite
return self._api.create_favorite(self.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_favorite'
```

And here is the code:

```
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxx')
auth.set_access_token('xxxx-xxxx','xxxxxx')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search = 'solana'
number_of_tweets = 50

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, search).items(number_of_tweets):
try:
    print('Tweet Liked')
    tweet.favorite()
    time.sleep(10)
except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
    print(e)
except StopIteration:
    break
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: hi @thebjorn, unfortunately, it does not. I am unable to see why it returned None :(

Comment: One of the `tweet` in `tweepy.Cursor(...)` is returned as `None`, you'll have to debug or read the docs to figure out why/when this would happen.

Comment: @thebjorn: if one of the tweets was `None`, the code wouldn't have got into the `favorite` method.  For some reason, the `Status` object created internally by tweepy doesn't have the `_api` object set on it.  As far as I can tell, this is a bug in tweepy.